# How do I make an interactive line chart

Tags: chart.js

I looked at the mini bar chart on the Charts.js home page. I couldn't understand how to convert that to an interactive line chart. Where are the helper functions documented? How do I apply them to line charts?

Answer (score 2):

Example

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

Data Structure

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]
};
```

You can see the documentation from this link [ChartJs-LineChart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-example-usage)